# Почему Python обнуляет срез если индекс среза имеет отрицательное значение?

Tags: python, список, списки

Подскажите почему обнуляется срез когда я беру отрицательный индекс. И можно ли как то обойти ограничение. Пробовал вместо среза брать числа по индексу и прогонять итерацией - тоже не получается.

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x = [c[z-2:z+3] for z in range(len(c))]
print(x)
```

получается:

```
[[], [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

а хотелось бы:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрицательные индексы считаются индексами с *конца* списка.

```
                    0      1      2      3      4    <----- Полоажительные индексы
                +------+------+------+------+------+
 Список ------> |      |      |      |      |      |
                +------+------+------+------+------+
                   -5     -4     -3     -2     -1    <----- Отрицательные  индексы
```

Например для вашего списка `c` и для `z == 0` будет `c[z-2:z+3] == c[-2:3] == c[3:3] == []`, потому что индекс `-2` (*второй элемент с конца* 5-элементного списка) есть его *третьим* элементом (считая от нуля).

Надо запретить отрицательные индексы:

```
x = [c[z-2:z+3] if z - 2 >= 0 else c[0: z+3]  for z in range(len(c))]
print(x)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]
> ```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,  c[z-2:z+3] == c[-2:3] == c[3:3] == []  - все правильно, но обнуляет не по этой причине, если взять список из 10 элементов, получим c[z-2:z+3] == c[-2:3] == c[3:8] , а ответ получится: [[], []...

Comment: В списке с **10** элементами будет индексу -2 соответствовать индекс **8**, *а не 3,* так что в конце получите **c[8:8]**, *а не c[3:8] .*

Answer (score 1):

При отрицательном индексе берется элемент с конца множества. -1 будет равен последнему элементу, -2 предпоследнему и так далее.